# UIButton change border color in different states in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm adding an `extension` to `UIButton` so that it changes it border color when `disabled/enabled`

```
extension UIButton {
    override public var enabled: Bool {
        didSet {
            if enabled {
                changeBorderColorForEnabled()
            } else {
                changeBorderColorForDisabled()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that ***sometimes*** the border color changes, but the title color doesn't.

Specifically, it happens when it changes too fast, like in the following piece of code, when it executes line `//==== 1. =====//` and `//==== 2. =====//`

```
       // Enabled by default
        self.priceButton.enabled = true   //==== 1. =====//

        if bought {
            self.priceButton.setTitle("bought", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        } else {
            if let price = self.product?.price {
                self.priceButton.setTitle("Buy for \(price)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            } else {

                // Disable if price hasn't been retrieved
                self.priceButton.enabled = false   //==== 2. =====//
            }
        }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It has nothing to do with _fast_. It has to do with _logic_. You are saying to set `enabled` to false so it is set to `false`. What does this have to do with "title color" anyway? I see no "title color" in your code. And since you don't show `changeBorderColorForEnabled`, no one knows what you might be doing there. If you want help, show your code; don't _conceal_ it.

Comment: when you change the state to enabled = false, by default, the title color changes

Comment: Okay, I'm with you. And what precisely goes wrong? Is it that the button is disabled but the title does not go gray?

Comment: Exactly, the button is disabled, but the title doesn't go gray. But this only happens in the sequence. If I just disable it, the text DO go gray

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that the problem is caused by the fact that, by interfering with UIButton's response to `setEnabled:`, you are drawing at the same time that the button is trying to draw - and that this is messing up the button's attempt to draw.

The first thing I would try is adding a short delay, to give the button a chance to do its own drawing first (for `delay`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/341994):

```
    didSet {
        delay(0.1) {
            if enabled {
                changeBorderColorForEnabled()
            } else {
                changeBorderColorForDisabled()
            }
        }
    }
```